# Need help with Sharepoint filters

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, view

So I have a list that I created different views for - for this specific view I need to show when "Column1" equals "A", "B", or "C AND when "Column2" contains "D" or when "Column3" equals "E"

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want you need to use the combination of multiple **And** and **Or** operators in your list view filters.

Check below image as an example of what you are trying to achieve:

[image]

You can create similar filtering on your views by replacing the actual column names and their values in your case.

**Official documentations**:

1. [Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9)
2. [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4)

Answer (score 0):

You could set filter in the view as following picture shows.

[image]